# Does MongoDB have a built in auth just as Firebase does?

Tags: mongodb

Firebase's auth is very useful and easy to use. Does MongoDB have this feature?

Comment: MongoDB has auth.

Comment: authing to a mongodb is usually straightforward. via a connection string `mongodb://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGO_URI}` ... user, pass and uri

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a loaded question, but most people use https://mongoosejs.com/ to write/read to their Mongodb database from a Nodejs application. You'll of course need Mongo installed locally or use an online sandboxed mongo database. You probably need more of a tutorial rather than a stack overflow question.

Comment: that's fine - still helpful though